# Learning Algorithm not working?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Learning Algorithm of Single layer precptons just works for only given training data, not for new input.Is there any way to correct this?

```
    private void traning(){
        while(true){
            int errorCount = 0;
            for( int i = 0 ; i < input_set_count ; i++ ){
                float weightSum = 0;
                for( int j = 0 ; j < no_input ; j++ ){                  
                    weightSum = weightSum + weight[j] * train_data[i][j];
                }
                int toutput = 0;
                if( weightSum >= threshold )
                    toutput = 1;                
                int error = output[i] - toutput;
                if( error != 0 )
                    errorCount++;

                for( int j = 0 ; j < no_input ; j++ ){
                    weight[j] = weight[j] + error * train_data[i][j] * learning_rate;
                }
            }
            if( errorCount == 0 )
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("Traning Completed...");   
    }
```

Comment: Please tell us what your input and output is. How can we test your function?

Comment: How can i give you the entire code? Its too big to post here.

Comment: while input is just a AND or OR funtion.

Comment: Describe a bit more. What does your function do? What do you want to achieve? What data is contained in train_data? You should ask yourself if you could find a solution with the informations you gave us?

Comment: yesterday i have gone through one post about neural networks, link is http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/introduction-to-artificial-neural-networks-part-2-learning/8 , I have done what they said. But they have give four training data for AND function, mine OR. But i gave only 3. But i have given me a wrong ouput. For 1 0 it's output is 0 but it has to be 1. At the last they said some Bias. Even that i don't get.

Comment: I don't understand your terminating condition, when will errorCount be equal to 0? It doesn't seem to be true at any time unless your inner for loop never executes.